# Parsing an Array of Json into a C# Class

Tags: c#, json

Here is my code:

```
Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), enc);
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
JsonTextReader jsreader = new JsonTextReader(loResponseStream);
results = (mHealthData)serializer.Deserialize(jsreader, typeof(mHealthData)); ***
loResponseStream.Close();

public class mHealthData
{ // Class for the Mhealth Data
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string source { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
        public double value { get; set; }
        public string timestamp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the error I receive On the line marked with a ********:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'MHealthPlugin.mHealthData' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like `List<T>` that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

I have no clue how to fix this. I've tried putting `List<mHealthData>` practically everywhere in the code and it doesn't help. The other rest Calls I do work fine.
For reference, here is an example of what the JSON I'm trying to parse looks like:

```
[{"source":"hi","name":"G","type":"number","unit":null,"value":126,"timestamp":"1974-07-27T09:35:12Z"},{"source":"hi","name":"G","type":"number","unit":null,"value":120,"timestamp":"1974-07-27T09:35:12Z"}]
```

Comment: you cant define a class as a list, right now, you just have a class named List<RootObject>.  its not actually a list or related to a list at all.

Comment: FYI: If you use JSON.NET (aka Newtonsoft.Json), there are one-liners for serializing to/from a string: deserializing can be done with `var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(myJson);`. Much nicer than dealing with all the streams and readers.

Comment: also, what type is your response variable?

Comment: My response variable is of type HTTPWebResponse named resp.  
I tried using 
` var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<mhealthData[]>(resp); `
 but I get the error Error 11 The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MHealthPlugin.mhealthData[]>(string, params Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: For the `JsonConvert` thing, you still need to start with a string. You can get the string from your HttpWebResponse object with a one-liner: `string responseText = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `mHealthData` class doesn't have anything in it, except a nested class. Take a step back and see how your data is supposed to be defined.

It looks like you want a `RootObject` class. In that case, the class should be:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string unit { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Then when you deserialize, you'll end up with an object of type `RootObject[]` - your JSON is simply an array, not an object containing an array.